# Normal mapping in Scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to add normal map for a 3D model in swift using SCNMaterial properties. The diffuse property is working but no other property including normal property is visible on the screen. When I debug to check if the node's material consists of the normal property, it shows the property exists with the image that I added.
I have also checked if the normal image that I am using is correct or not in the SceneKit Editor where it works fine.
I have added the code that I am using.

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.lightGray
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.normal.contents = UIImage(named: "normal")
node.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

**This is the output I am getting**

[image: Screen Shot]

**I am expecting something like this**
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution. Since I did not enable DefaultLighting, there was no lighting in the scene. Added this to the code.

```
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the screenshot, it seems like there is no lighting in the scene, or the material does not respond to lighting, since the sphere is not shaded. For a normal map to work, lighting has to be taken into account, because it responds to lighting direction. Have you tried creating an entirely new SCNMaterial and played with its properties? (I.E. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterial/lightingmodel seems interesting)

I would try setting

```
node.geometry!.firstMaterial!.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, lighting was the issue. I had tried adding lighting model but it did not work. I had to set sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting=true, then only it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let scene =  SCNScene()
let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "normal.png")

let sphereNode = SCNNode()
sphereNode.geometry = sphere
sphereNode.geometry?.materials = [sphereMaterial]
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0.5,0.1,-1)

scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
sceneView.scene = scene
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sphereMaterial.diffuse is working fine but sphereMaterial.normal is not working in this code too.